# How to change epilogue of a mocha spec reporter

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, mocha.js

I'm trying to change epilogue of a reporter so it would be outputting email friendly html. I need to find how to remove chunk from reporter and add `<br />` instead of `n/`. In addition I use spec reporter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the file that's creating baseRepoter object for example if you use webdriverio it will be BaseReporter.js (I sure it will be always BaseReporter.js but I did't check other examples) look here for more information: https://mochajs.org/api/mocha.reporters.base if you want to remove chunk as well i suggest to use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-html